# PostgreSQL function defined in column

Tags: postgresql, function, triggers

I have been trying to find this online but I'm new to postgresql and I probably don't know enough to quickly filter out search results..

I have declared 2 tables, `country` and `person`, where each `person` has a `country`:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE country_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE country
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('country_id_seq'),
  name character varying(40) NOT NULL,
  validator regproc,
  CONSTRAINT country_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE SEQUENCE person_id_seq;
CREATE TABLE person
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('person_id_seq'),
  first_name character varying(40) NOT NULL,
  country_id integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT person_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT person_fk_country_id FOREIGN KEY (country_id)
      REFERENCES country (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
);
```

Each `country` has a `validator` which is a function where I add the following:

```
CREATE FUNCTION validator_PT(name text) RETURNS boolean AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN FALSE;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

INSERT INTO country(id, name,validator) VALUES(1, 'Portugal','validator_PT');
INSERT INTO country(id, name) VALUES(2, 'Italia');
```

Now I want to create a trigger function on `person` that will use `country[person.country_id].validor` to validate `person.first_name`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_person_validate_name() RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
  validator regproc;
BEGIN
  IF NEW.country_id IS NOT NULL THEN
    validator := validator FROM country WHERE id = NEW.country_id;

    IF validator IS NOT NULL THEN
      IF NOT validator(NEW.first_name) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Invalid first name: %', NEW.first_name;
      END IF;
    END IF;
  END IF;

  RETURN NEW;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_person_validate_name_insert
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON person
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_person_validate_name();
```

In short, I want to call the function configured in `country.validator` but, doing what I am doing, I get:

```
INSERT INTO person(first_name, country_id) VALUES('john',1)

ERROR: function validator(character varying) does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

So it tries to execute `validator` function instead of `validator_PT`.
I've also tried using `EXECUTE`:

```
DECLARE
    validator regproc;
    valid boolean;
BEGIN
  ...
  EXECUTE 'SELECT $1($2)' INTO valid USING validator, NEW.first_name;
  IF NOT valid THEN
  ...
```

But it fails with:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "("
```

Referring to the `EXECUTE` line.
What is the proper way to do this? (I can change the schema of the table if required of course)

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3

Comment: This INSERT statement can't work, because last_name is declared `not null`: `INSERT INTO person(first_name, country_id) VALUES('john',1)`. Think about adding the trigger itself, too. (CREATE TRIGGER statement.) What version of PostgreSQL? (Output of `select version();`.)

Comment: Yes you're right, this was copied from the real scenario and modified, though the INSERT is not the point here and I assumed the information available was enough as well. I didn't add the trigger definition either as it doesn't mean much for the actual question and it would only make the text bigger. But I'll edit, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was brought to my attention ([IRL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_real_life)) that I was misusing `EXECUTE USING` for this and should be through direct concatenation (at least the function name) like [here](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/428C8ACB.3050402@archonet.com) such as:

```
DECLARE
    validator regproc;
    valid boolean;
BEGIN
  ...
  EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || validator || '($1)' INTO valid USING NEW.first_name;
  IF NOT valid THEN
  ...
```

Problem solved (though it would still be nice to know if there's any way to achieve this without `EXECUTE`)